# Angular 4- call a function inside subscribe

Tags: angular, service, subscribe

I have a function

```
isNull(name: string, lname: string): void {
  if (name === null || lname === null)
    alert("User not found");
}
```

and I call this function inside the subscribe

```
callSearchService($event) {
  this.searchService.searchUser(this.firstName, this.lastName)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("we got: ", data);
        this.isNull(data.firstname, data.lastname);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      }
   );
}
```

but this function doesnot work . Can you help me ?

Comment: Any errors in the console

Comment: @Sachila Ranawaka no there are no errors

Comment: does the console log print the value ?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka yes it prints nulls

Comment: does the console log give you data.firstname and data.lastname? (in data)

Comment: @V.TS if the `data` is null then you can't access the `data.firstname` values

Comment: This must throw a console error

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Yes and both are nulls (and it is correct)

Comment: 'we got:  {firstName: null, lastName: null} ' this is what console prints and there are no errors

Comment: What does searchService.searchUser returns? As i understand data is null, but does searchService.searchUser returns the correct observable?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your browser let alerts, 
then debug inside the isNull() or console.log 2 items (name,lname) inside the method.
you don't want to use '===' 
this could work

```
isNull(name: string, lname: string): void {
 if (!name || !lname)
// you can use console.log(name + " " + lname)
  alert("User not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Use***

```
isNull(name: string, lname: string): void {
 if (!!name || !!lname)
  alert("User not found");
}
```

**instead of**

```
isNull(name: string, lname: string): void {
 if (name === null || lname === null)
  alert("User not found");
}
```

Comment: I don't think using `==` is a very good idea as it ignores the type checking.

Comment: You can use the method `isNull()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use double equals. Double equals checks for null or undefined. It is the only time you should use double equals instead of triple equals.

```
isNull(name: string, lname: string): void {
  console.log(name, lname)
  if (name == null || lname == null) console.error('User not found');
  else {
    console.log('we got the user')
  }
}
```

Comment: I used double equals but now alert is appearing in both cases if name and lname are not null and if they are null

Comment: it will appear if they are undefined also